# Resolve Q while using breeze.angular.js in the case of hasMetadataFor in breeze

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I am using breeze.angular.js in my spa. Thats why I am not using q.js for angular promise as mentioned in breeze documentation. but in the case of hasMetadata true from MetadataStore, it returns Q(true), which demads the q.js.... Is there anything to do to resolve Q through breeze.angular.js.... If anyone can help me with this, it would be great.

Comment: Breeze has an adapter for using Q.js in angular - http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-labs/breezeangularqjs

Comment: Thanks PW Kad, breeze has declared a new way to use breeze angular promise. http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service . In this case I miss the Q inside the factory which accepts the breeze service.